# Restore MySQL schema from mysqldump

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php-5.5

I created an ubuntu vitural machine, and I'm trying to restore a db schema from a `mysqldump` file. The file is 5560 lines of SQL, so I'll spare you the details. I did not generate the dump, but it looks like it's formatted the same as I've seen through google.

```
jordan@jordan-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ mysql -u [my login] -p [db name] < schemadump.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.' at line 1
```

The issue here is that it looks like it's trying to parse comments as SQL, so it's throwing a syntax error. I'm using the latest `PHP5.5.9` and the latest `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38`, but I'm not sure the version of mysql that it came from. Would that effect the `mysqldump` output? Or are there settings I need to enable on my server?

The sql file starts out like:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: [not so fast haxors]    Database: [my db name]
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

Comment: Can you post the first ~10 lines of the dump here?

Comment: @lxg sure thing, just a moment

Comment: Did you maybe create the file on a different plattform than the one on which you're importing? If so, which are they? Source seems to be Debian, target also some Linux/Unix?

Comment: I did, and I just solved it. Unarchiving the .tar on OSX and moving to ubuntu caused the wrong line endings. Unarchiving on the VM made it work

Comment: Yeah, that's a common one. Next time, have a look at `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was that I was unarchiving the tar file that the backup.sql file was in on OSX, when my server is on an ubuntu VM.

Unarchiving on the VM and running the same command worked, meaning the line endings differ between OSX and ubuntu